# Insert shortcode in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code in Functions.php

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbbbloomer_custom_action', 30 );
function bbbbloomer_custom_action() {
echo '<div style="float:left"><a class="btnproduct third datlichthuao" href="#openModal1">Đặt lịch thử áo</a><a class="btnproduct third goilaichotoi" href="#openModal2" >Gọi lại cho tôi</a><a class="btnproduct third chatvoituvan" href="https://www.facebook.com/Marymy.HauteCouture/?ref=br_rs" target="_black">Chat với Tư Vấn</a><a class="btnproduct third tuvan" href="callto:0995999986">Gọi tư vấn</a></div>

<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
     [contact-form-7 id="74" title="Contact Form - Basic"]
</div>
</div>
<div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
 [contact-form-7 id="74" title="Contact Form - Basic"]
</div>
</div>
<div    style="clear:both"></div>';
}
```

But the shortcode "[contact-form-7 id="74" title="Contact Form - Basic"]" not load when click the modal, it just text like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQDFn.jpg). So how I can show the content in this shortcode ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this format

```html
 
    
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_custom_action', 30 );

function bbloomer_custom_action() {

        ?>  
            <div style="float:left">
            <a class="btnproduct third datlichthuao" href="#openModal1">Đặt lịch thử 
            áo</a>
            <a class="btnproduct third goilaichotoi" href="#openModal2" >Gọi lại cho 
            tôi</a>
            <a class="btnproduct third chatvoituvan" 
            href="https://www.facebook.com/Marymy.HauteCouture/?ref=br_rs" 
            target="_black">Chat với Tư Vấn</a>
            <a class="btnproduct third tuvan" href="callto:0995999986">Gọi tư vấn</a>
            </div>

            <div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="74" title="Contact Form - Basic"]');  ?>
                
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="openModal2" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
              <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="74" title="Contact Form - Basic"]');  ?>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        
        
        <?php
    
    }
```

Comment: @TriHoang can you mark this answer so that for other users it will be easy to locate the answer

Answer (score 0):

Inside `functions.php` file wordpress hook does not apply automatically. what you need to do is, use `do_shortcode` function and echo the returned html content. like

```
echo do_shortcode('[your_shortcode]');
```